# How can I access files on a remote server from a vpn with same web addess

Tags: dns, remote-access, vpn, shared-hosting

I am hosting a web app on a Digital Ocean VPN. I set up an A record via GoDaddy to point my domain to the VPN server. I'm wondering if there is a way to still access public files from within the web app that I have on GoDaddy shared hosting at that same address.

I basically want to access a file at http://example.com/uploads/somedoc.pdf

Which would be at the following path on the GoDaddy server:
home/site/public_html/uploads/...

But example.com now points to the VPN. I tried using the GoDaddy website IP address instead in the URL but that doesn't work either. I get a 404 file not found error even though the files are actually in the uploads folder. I figure it's looking for them on the VPN instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem I solved my issue by simply adding an A Record for a subdomain in my DNS zone file and I was able to point my VPN server IP to that subdomain. So with my web app being served at app.example.com I was successfully able to access the files on the GoDaddy shared server from my web app (ie example.com/uploads/somefile.docx).

To ensure that the client would still visit the web app at the new subdomain I setup a permanent redirect to send all traffic from example.com to app.example.com instead of them having to remember to type the subdomain each time they want to access the web app.